# How do I make a page update between multi-user input

Tags: html, node.js, canvas, cloud, ejs

As a very simple example I have made, I have a square in a canvas. I log onto the server(cloud 9) and want to be able to move the square on one computer and automatically, without or even with reloading the page, seeing the change. My goal is to have multiple characters under control of multiple people in a competitive game. Here is a link to the project, it is running right now and I will keep it running.

https://spar-project-humzah.c9users.io/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will need to have javascript code that uses ajax to communicate with your server. You can have mouse events or time events that call an ajax function that will provide updates about the square and request updates from the other player's square movements. The server will need to be listening for these requests and track the position of all the squares. Since you didn't mention ajax I would guess that is the first thing you should familiarize yourself with. Ajax will allow you 2-way communication between a page and a server without having to reload. I would recommend checking out w3schools for information on Ajax.